# Error en el render de React y al import y export routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Tengo insalada la v6 del react-router-dom

Deduzco que el error está en cómo importo y exporto los archivos que están dentro de la carpeta pages, y como estos le llegan al archivo index.js

Interpreto que hay algo mal en el archivo de ChatApp.jsx. o en el Index.jsx, ya que fue al introducir este archivo último cuando me volvió a salir el error.

Anteriormente, también había tenido problemas que solucioné, cambiando Switch por Routes, withRoutes por useNavigate y component por elemment

Pero ahora por más vueltas y modificaciones que hago no encuentro dónde está el error. Alguien puede iluminarme o derivarme a documentación que me aclare. Busco pero no encuentro

Error que me muestra React al compilar

`````
ERROR in ./src/ChatApp.jsx 71:38-47
export 'default' (imported as 'IndexPage') was not found in './Pages/IndexPage' (possible exports: IndexPage)

ERROR in ./src/ChatApp.jsx 83:43-52
export 'default' (imported as 'LoginPage') was not found in './Pages/LoginPage' (possible exports: LoginPage)

ERROR in ./src/index.js 17:38-45
export 'default' (imported as 'ChatApp') was not found in './ChatApp' (possible exports: ChatApp)````

Muestro el código

Archivo chatApp
```import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import LoginPage from "./Pages/LoginPage";
import RegisterPage from "./Pages/RegisterPage";
import DashboardPage from "./Pages/DashboardPage";
import IndexPage from "./Pages/IndexPage";
import RoomPage from "./Pages/RoomPage";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import makeToast from "./Toaster";
 
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        {/* <Route path="/" element={<IndexPage />} exact /> */}
        <Route path="/" element={<IndexPage />} exact />

        {/* <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} exact /> */}
        <Route
          path="/login"
          render={() => <LoginPage setupSocket={setupSocket} />}
          exact
        />
        <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterPage />} exact />

        {/* <Route path="/dasboard" element={<DashboardPage />} exact /> */}
        <Route
          path="/dashboard"
          render={() => <DashboardPage socket={socket} />}
          exact
        />

        {/*<Route path="/room" element={<RoomPage />} exact />*/}
        <Route
          path="/room/:id"
          render={() => <RoomPage socket={socket} />}
          exact
        />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}```


Achivo Index

```import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ChatApp from "./ChatApp";
//!
import "./styles/index.css";
import "./styles/room.css";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ChatApp />, rootElement);

```

IndexPage

```import React from "react";

export const IndexPage = (props) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("CC_Token");
    console.log(token);
    if (!token) {
      props.history.push("/login");
    } else {
      props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [0]);
  return <div></div>;
};
```
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error hace referencia a la forma en que estas exportando tu archivo `jsx` como `export const ...`, por lo que no tienes una exportación por defecto al llamarlo en el `import` correspondiente.

Tienes la opción de dejar tu componente como está, y cambiar la importación por

```
import { LoginPage } from '../tuRuta'
```

o cambiar el componente a una exportación por defecto

```
const LoginPage = () => {
   // implementacion
}

export default LoginPage
```

De esta manera, vas a poder llamar a tu import sin problemas como lo estás haciendo ahora.

Comment: Muchas gracias Paulo, ya solucioné ese error Además me quedó más claro lo de import/export